# proftpd not working?

Tags: ftp

i've done some updates on my server , after which ftp stopped working !

proftpd is running and listening on port 21 ,
port 21 is open in the firewall !

but still all i get from filezilla is :

```
Status: Resolving address of xxx
Status: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: How have you verified that proftpd is "running and listening"?  If you try this *on the system running proftpd*, what happens?

Comment: If your proftpd is running what does the proftpd.log file ( possibly located at /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log) say ?

Comment: hmmm , failed binding to :: , port 21: address already in use !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if proftpd is running

```
ps -ef | grep proftpd
proftpd  15530     1  0 21:26 ?        00:00:00 proftpd: (accepting connections)
iain     15731 13855  0 21:49 pts/1    00:00:00 grep proftpd
```

To find out what is bound to port 21

```
sudo lsof -i :21
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
proftpd 15530 proftpd    1u  IPv6 1641458      0t0  TCP *:ftp (LISTEN)
```

The output you get from the above should help you narrow things down a bit.

Edit

The problem you are seeing is likely because you are starting it in standalone mode but inetd is still configured  to manage the service. You need to disable this inetd behaviour . Have a look at [this page on the proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch4.html) website - point 3 is relevant.

Comment: ok , i got 'inetd' running on port 21 !!!

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero: See my edit for a possible explanation /  solution

Comment: I've commented out the line starting with 'ftp' in /etc/inet.d , then i killed all inetd to force it to restart and read the new config , restarted proftpd and am happy now :) could update some features on my ut video converting site :) thanks guys