# ProFTP on MacPorts: Connection refused

Tags: ftp, mac-osx, proftpd, osx-lion

I have a MacPorts installed ProFTPD daemon installed. It worked like a charm for a year. Now it does not work at all anymore. All I get is

#### Connection refused

```
ftp localhost
Trying ::1...
ftp: Can't connect to `::1': Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
ftp: Can't connect to `127.0.0.1': Connection refused
Trying fe80::1%lo0...
ftp: Can't connect to `fe80::1%lo0': Connection refused
ftp: Can't connect to `localhost'
```

I wrote to MacPorts and ProFTP, but no answers there as of yet so I hope someone here can help me out.

#### Troubleshooting

Found some troubleshooting tips [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/227309/proftpd-not-working).
When I check for ProTPD processes I get

```
ps -ef | grep proftpd
    0    58     1   0  4Aug13 ??         0:00.77 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=proftpd --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper restart ; --pid=none
  501 27233 26992   0  1:42PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep proftpd
```

So it seems some processes are running. But not the needed ProFTPD process.

When I used the following command to see if port 21 is active:

```
sudo lsof -i :21
```

I get zero results. So ProFTPD is clearly not running and port 21 is not active which is the regular FTP port.

#### Question

Does anyone here know what I am missing here? I need it back to to the sweet any easy updating of local website copies.

#### Update

ProFTPD Configuration file is here http://pastebin.com/4VvSHz5p . Even though it is a basic setup there does not seem to be anything wrong with it. @Janne Pikkarainen mentioned it was missing directories, but in the end this was not the issue.

#### Update 2 Debug Commands

Asked by GioMac I tried `sudo proftpd -n -d 10`. Command was not found. The command `sudo /opt/local/sbin/proftpd -n -d 10` did work and gave us some clues

#### Update 3 Re-installation Port

I reinstalled all as suggested by GioMac and that did not work either. Still had the same errors.

#### Update 4 The Solution: Proper (re)starting ProFTDP

Then I ran `sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper start` as suggested by @GioMac. Running similar command from sbin and bin did not work. And then I tested the FTP connection again.

```
sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper start
Password:
```

Command worked and I had no errors. ProFTPD was (re)started like this again. Then I did the ultimate test to see if I could FTP locally again:

```
jaspersmbp:etc jasper$ cd
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ ftp jasper@localhost
Trying ::1...
ftp: Can't connect to `::1': Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
220 ProFTPD 1.3.3e Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [127.0.0.1]
331 Password required for jasper
Password: 
230 User jasper logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
```

Eureka! Connection could be made again and I could also update my local WordPress installations again.

Comment: No, it's not running, try to run proftpd manually with "sudo proftpd -n -d 10" for debug

Comment: `sudo proftpd -n -d 10
sudo: proftpd: command not found`
so proftpd is not running after all I guess..

Comment: sudo /opt/local/bin/proftpd -n -d 10

Comment: Hmm odly enough the binary is not in `/opt/local/bin` :
`sudo /opt/local/bin/proftpd -n -d 10
sudo: /opt/local/bin/proftpd: command not found`

even though I installed it and `port installed | grep proftpd
  proftpd @1.3.3e_0 (active)`

Comment: sudo /opt/local/sbin/proftpd -n -d 10

Comment: Seems to be working. I see http://pastebin.com/ZNpsZGj9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's something wrong with this file, probably something changed in the system or package is broken. Try to reinstall...

```
/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper
```

[Use fink instead](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/) - these builds are more stable for me.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling has been taken care of, but I still have the connection refused. Stop using MacPorts for Fink or Homebrew is something I want to avoid if I can. The next Mac I buy will probably get Homebrew, but this MBP will keep MacPorts if possible.

Comment: OK, let's continue investigation. "sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.proftpd/proftpd.wrapper start". Also, please upload contents of this file and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! See updated question. Not sure why this was necessary though. Should have been running already..

Comment: OK, looks like problem with /opt/local/bin/daemondo or running script :S

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper that tries to start/stop/restart ProFTPd seems to be running, but not the ProFTPd itself. The reasons that can lead to this that come up to my mind:

- A typo or two in ProFTPd configuration file
- ProFTPd pid file configured to be in a directory where it does not have permissions to write
- Bad permissions in ProFTPd data directory
- Something changed in authentication which ProFTPd is configured to use
- Just a broken build of ProFTPd itself.

What happens if you try to start ProFTPd from shell manually? Like, `/path/to/proftpd/binary`?

Comment: Config of ProFTPD I added as a pasty here: http://pastebin.com/4VvSHz5p Looking for the path atm.

Comment: Err, is that all? No <Directory> etc parameters at all, so ProFTPd has no idea what directories to serve. I hope you have some additional config files somewhere. If not, your ProFTPd config file is severely lacking the meat.

Comment: Well, I  guess I did as all worked and connections were not refused.. But no idea where.